# How to pass comma seperated string as argument to Mongo Script?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell, scripting, export-csv

I am having the below mongo cursor logic which taked comma seperated string as input for $in condition.

```
student.js
==========
db.getCollection('student').aggregate([
  { $match : { id : {$in: [
      '100','101','102']} } }
])
```

And then i am dumping the result set of above query into csv file using the below bash script :

```
student.sh
==========

#!/usr/bin/env bash

IDS_FILE="$1"
auth=""
host="localhost:27017"

while IFS=$'\r' read -r id || [[ -n "$id" ]]; do

echo "id ::" $id
ids=$ids','"'$id'"
ids="${ids}"

done < "${IDS_FILE}"

id="${ids:1}"
echo $id

mongo --quiet ${auth} ${host}/school --eval "var id = $id" student.js >> out.csv
```

I am running the above script file using below command for which ids.txt is input,

```
./student.sh ids.txt
```

And this ids.txt contains students id's as below.

```
ids.txt
=======
1
2
3
```

I am getting below id's printed like this in this echo line number of above mentioned student.sh file,

```
echo $id

'1','2','3'
```

which is absolutely expected, but when i a trying to send those $id values to student.js $in condition via below mongo command i am getting below error,

```
mongo --quiet ${auth} ${host}/school --eval "var id = $id" student.js >> out.csv
```

in the above var id = $id id is replaced with `'1','2','3'`

## Error:

```
E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing variable name @(shell eval):1:
```

Can anyone help me in understanding how to pass comma separated string from shell script mongo command to .js file with **$in** query?

I have tried with multiple argumnets/fields in mongo command which is working, but how to send multiple string separated by comma to one single argument/field in Mongo script?

Thanks in advance.